# How to start Kentico11 CMSScheduler service from commandline

Tags: kentico-11

Web server running Kentico v11.  We use Kentico CMSScheduler to kick off various Scheduled Tasks, particularly the sending of email.  Per enterprise policy, the web server is rebooted on a weekly schedule. When the reboot occurs, the Kentico CMSScheduler (Kentico11_CMSScheduler does not start.

We have tried using the start type of 'Automatic' and 'Automatic (Delayed Start)', but this does not resolve the issue. Is there a way to start the Kentico CMSScheduler outside of the Kentico Service Manager or the Services applet?  Thank you.